# IHE profile transacctions and HL7 message triggers

Tags: profile, hl7

I'm trying to look for HL7 messages and events related to the transactions in the IHE profiles operations. For example, I know that inside the PAM profile there is an ITI-30 transaction, this one contains HL7 ADT_A05 messages and this message uses the triggers A28 and A31. I want to know the same information for the next profiles: XDS, PIX/PDQ and MEM. I've read a lot of documentation (extra and official) but I'm not able to found this information.

If it's possible, I would know about some example in HL7 v2.5+ using web services.

By other way, for the HL7 messages sent usign web services, it is possible to send information encapsulated with ER7 or must be in XML format?

Thanks.

Comment: Which documents (exactly) from the list http://www.ihe.net/Technical_Frameworks did you already went through? What do you use as reference dictionary for your acronyms?

Comment: I've revised the IT Infrastructur, all the volumes. I'm looking for a direct relation, like a table: transaction | triggers | HL7 messages.

Comment: Your question is little bit too fat, consider splitting it into multiple [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) questions. Finding a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource is not on the list (§4). I don't know what is the answer but for example it seems that `XDS` profile does not directly map to a HL7 messages. See http://www.slideshare.net/nzhug/ihe-crossenterprise-document-sharing-xds and http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/fhir/usecases.html#xds

Comment: Yes,  it's a big question. Maybe I need more investigation. Thanks for the approach.

Comment: The ADT_A05 message, as the name suggest, is A05 trigger event. It cannot contain A28 or A31 messages in it. For these two there are ADT_A28 and ADT_A31 messages respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try IHE Profiles page and choose domains that you need - http://wiki.ihe.net/index.php?title=Profiles